# Lotus Notes 8.5.2FP2 - "Remote system no longer responding" while replicating specific application

Tags: lotus-notes

Since last yesterday in December we upgraded people's Notes client to Windows 7, Notes8.5.2FP2 and the issue has been noticed and reported.

It occurs on remote users connected via Internet+VPN.
Users have many applications replicated from the same server to their local.
And whiling replicating, most applications could send and receive updates with the server without any problem.
But with a specific application(database), the replicator first shows "Searching..." for a long while, and then it shows "Receiving... 10 out of 12,200 updates; about XXX minutes remaining."
For me, this message means the clicne has reached the server and the replication is on going.
But after a while, maybe 1 or 2 minutes, then it's stopped and shows "Remote system no longer responding. Failed with [XXXXXXX-server name]"

How come?

In the company we have more than 50 servers around the world and this problem is only experienced and reported from one country/server.
Is this an issue on the server end or on the local end?

Looking forward to any suggestions.

Comment: Not much to go on. Upgraded from what? What was the manner of the upgrade? What version is the Domino server? What errors (if any) are you getting on the domino console. If the client connection/connection document OK? Also Adding CLIENT_CLOCK=3 to the notes.ini of the client might give you more details in the logs (in IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder).

Comment: It's to upgrade the client machines from WinXP+Notes8.02 to be Win7+Notes8.52. The Domino server version is 8.5.2FP1. The client connection document is OK. Let's say the client replicates 10 applications with the same server but only one particular application encounters this problem.

Comment: Apart from CLIENT_CLOCK logs, I'd also check the replication settings to see if it has been changed, along with the frequency and amount of data that is changed in the database between replications.

Comment: The frequency is set to run every 15 minutes. The problem may be because the user has not replicated for rather long time (more than a month) and there are more than 12,000 updates to replicate for this application. Would this be the problem? I don't see there is any limitation setting on how many updates it can handle at a time... Is there such limitaton?

Answer (score 1):

We've had a similar issue, where over VPN the replication wasn't working. It turned out to be a DNS problem.

We solved it with a workaround on the client: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and enter the IP address of the server hosting the troublesome application. This will create a temporary location document for that session, and it should then replicate the data.

Otherwise speak with your networking team to look at the DNS routing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bandwidth issue or a network latency issue or some kind of routing problem where too many packets are being dropped. You need to involve your network team and have them get to the root cause of it.

Assuming normal usage doesn't require downloading 12,000+ updates, you could maybe create the replicas for the users and send them to them some other way and then when they needed the replicate they'd only need to replica the few newest updates each time.